# Null reference exception on string that correctly outputs to the console

Tags: c#, exception, selenium, reference, null

I have a Selenium test script written in c# that is entering a search value and then looking up a specific result from the returned search results.  My issue is I keep getting a "null reference exception" on the result string.  The confusing thing is, if I output the string to the console (simple Console.WriteLn statement) it prints the string just fine.  It's only when I try to do something with the string that the exception is thrown.  Any ideas why this might be happening?

relevant code below:

```
IWebElement listElement2 = driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("FixedTables"));
itemsList = new List<IWebElement>(listElement2.FindElements(By.TagName("a")));
foreach (IWebElement item in itemsList)
{
    string comparator = item.GetAttribute("onclick");
    Console.WriteLine(comparator);//this works to print the string....
    //if (comparator.Contains(somestring))//this fails and throws the exception
    //{
    //    item.Click();
    //    break;
    //}
}
```

Edit: I changed up the code to look like this:

```
    string comparator = item.GetAttribute("onclick");
    Console.WriteLine(comparator);
    if (comparator == null) Console.WriteLine("Is Null");
    if (somestring == null) Console.WriteLine("Somestring is Null");
```

This is my output from the console:

get_emp_risk_details('560', '');

Is Null

get_emp_risk_details('490', '');

Is Null

Comment: Silly question: what is the `somestring` set to in your example code?  Is it null?  If I try `MyString.Contains(MyNullStringVar)` I get a `ArgumentNullException`

Comment: Some string is a variable that has a value - I've also tried variations of the code with string literal ("something") and still get the exception.  Additionally - I tested by just referencing a character out of the string array (i.e. Console.WriteLn(comparator[1])) and that threw an exception also.  It's very weird....

Comment: What is output when you write comparator out to the Console? WriteLine will not throw an exception if you pass it a null variable.

Comment: It outputs a string that is the value I'm looking for and it's about 50 characters long (it's a javascript call that I'm looking for a specific value being passed to it in the "onclick" event)

Comment: What do you get if you try the first code block in my answer below (which I just edited)?

Comment: Addendum: it's only when I try to do something other than output to console that it throws the exception, for example if I change my Console.WriteLn to Console.Writeln(comparator + "hello") - null reference exception and the string that gets printed looks like this: get_emp_risk_details('1028', '');

Comment: When I use the suggested code it works, the problem is I'm getting a value and I need that value - my test looks up the correct link and then clicks it based on the "onclick" value.  I'm beginning to think this might be a selenium bug but it's weird that console.writeln works and seems to see the string but nothing else does

Comment: But in my suggested code, does it execute the Console.WriteLine or the second block? And if it does the WriteLine, what does it write?

Comment: sorry for the delay - driving home - selenium version is 2.31.2.0

@user1177636 - can't use id because the link doesn't have one it only has the onclick property.  That said tomorrow I'm going to try your css selector alternative and see if that works better.

hatchet - the block didn't execute as though the string was  null - interestingly when I put somestring.length as the first argument of the && operation I get a null reference exception

Comment: I edited my response some test changes - I'm still at a loss for how this is occurring.

Comment: @user1177636 I will try that solution tomorrow - thank you!

Comment: @user1177636 I put a delay before the variable assignment as you suggested but I'm still getting null reference exception so I'm at a loss - The site developers apparently changed the encoding of the php file to utf-8 - would that cause this?  if so would there be a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

If `somestring` is null, `Contains` will throw a null reference exception. That would fit your symptoms (comparator has a value, but you still get a null reference exception).

[String.Contains](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa.aspx)

Note in the Exceptions section that `ArgumentNullException` is thrown if value is null, for `Contains(value)`.

A safer way to code that for .Net 4.0 and later would be

```
if (comparator == null) {
    Console.WriteLine("comparator="+comparator);
} else {
    if ((!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(somestring)) && comparator.Contains(somestring)) }
    item.Click();
    break;
}
```

or

```
if ((somestring != null) && (somestring.Length > 0)
    && comparator.Contains(somestring))
{
    item.Click();
    break;
}
```

for earlier .Net versions.

Comment: see my comment above - somestring is not null and I've tried using a literal in it's place.  Also any operation on comparator throws an exception, for example comparator.length or comparator + "sometext".